# How to reuse some steps from one yaml to another in Opentest

Tags: automation, opentest

Lets suppose we have 2 yaml for android app containing:

1. Login
2. Performing some operation after Login

I want to reuse the Login yaml in yaml 2 , is it possible to achieve this in opentest somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to reuse the same logic in multiple tests is to create a macro action and call that macro in all the tests that need to run that logic. For more information on creating and using macros, please see the [OpenTest documentation](https://getopentest.org/docs/test-action-types.html#macro-actions).